# Facebook Open Graph Watch Action Rejected

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-opengraph

We are facing certain issues regarding Open Graph Action (watch).

We've been submitting the Action through the App developer page couple of times by now but every time we got the reply “The App requires some changes before it can be accepted”.

We have also used the action (watch) through Auth dialogue Test User and it works fine.
Here is a screenshot of the Action published through a test user.

[image]

This is not the first time we are using an Open Graph Action. We have used it on couple of our Apps earlier too but this time it has been rejected more than thrice.

Here is a screen shot of the steps etc that we did while submitting the Action (As we always do):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ask the facebook guys to tell you which user IDs they use to test and test it with that exact user. Just keep in mind:

- when you 'create' a test user and 'authorize' it in app admin panel, it doesn't assign the needed permissions (e.g. stream post etc.). So you need to check permissions and scope separately in you app (via js-sdk or php-sdk etc.)
- test users can't access any information from regular users or vice-versa. So keep in mind that your aggregation should do something between two test users
- Test users cannot like pages, so don't place your app behind a like gate.