# Facebook Open graph App rejected 3 times for Unknown reason

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have developed an facebook chat app at http://apps.facebook.com/chatboss/ .

My chat action is `chat` and object is `chat room`.It works fine in more than 10 test users i have created.But each time i submit it for approval, it gets rejected saying

```
App is not Performing actions that is mentioned,Please test with auth test users before submitting again
```

But activity is posted all time.below is the screen shot.

[image]

P.s :

---> I have created more than 10 test users and it works fine with all of them.

---> I am sure Facebook team can enter my app successfully (They post message as "test" with their auth users in my chat app xD)

---> Its rejected for 3 times for same reason.I have no clue in what test users they are testing :P

Comment: Please provide the full rejection reason along with your full description for an OG action you sent

Comment: +1 - why are Facebook saying the action was rejected? is the reason accurate?

Comment: And similar problem to this user http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12008442/facebook-open-graph-watch-action-rejected

Comment: Have you posted actions using the test user which is pre-associated with the app for testing actions / the auth dialog? if facebook created a new test user and went to your site, would the functionality work?

Comment: Yea i have used default auth user and also created extra 10 test users , It posts activity every time.I have attached screenshot too. I dont know why its not working with test user which facebook team is using for testing.

Comment: please see this question too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12640706/facebook-wont-approve-action

Answer (score 0):

Ask the facebook guys to tell you which user IDs they use to test and test it with that exact user. Just keep in mind:

- when you 'create' a test user and 'authorize' it in app admin panel, it doesn't assign the needed permissions (e.g. stream post etc.). So you need to check permissions and scope separately in you app (via js-sdk or php-sdk etc.)
- test users can't interact with regular users or vice-versa. So keep in mind that your aggregation should do something between two test users
- Test users cannot like pages, so don't place your app behind a like gate.

Comment: yea , I use php sdk to check the permission publish_actions , If its not granted, my app is redirected to permission page.